# Show that $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh ax}dx=\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}\right)^2$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

Show that
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh ax}dx=\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}\right)^2$$

using 2 ways: the first using contour integration and the second using real analysis.

Comment: If you did not have 50+ questions and 20+ answers under your belt, here is the comment I would have posted: "Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need."

Comment: @Did : thanks , Iam tried to study complex integration without teacher because after 3 years iam going to study it at university because of that I faced many difficult on my way , I asked alot of question about that and really the answer give me alot of information ,another problem I cant say what I have tried or where is iam stuck because of my weak english language especialy at question of contour integration which need alot of word ,so iam asking to get full answer and get from that answer what exactly I need... I study with my self  , there is no teacher with me ,my teacher is my computer.

Comment: also at the near future there is alot of question with same style because of same argument above

Comment: I know I have answered a very similar question of yours using a rectangular contour.  Have a look at that answer and attempt the question.  If you are still having a problem, let us know here what it is.

Comment: It is a bad idea to omit any personal thought on the questions you ask, due to (perceived) language difficulties. Lots of MSE users are not native English speakers hence everybody is used to decipher less-than-perfect prose in English. In the end I reiterate my urge to conform to the site guidelines by adding your personal thoughts.

Comment: For example... in the case at hand, how does the posted answer help you? Depending on your familiarity with the subject, this answer could be much too elementary or much too advanced. How will we know unless you stop posting questions without any information about the approaches you tried to solve them, the troubles you met while doing so, and so on?

Comment: BTW in case you forgot, here is the problem I solved for you.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454491/show-that-int-0-infty-fracx-cos-ax-sinh-xdx-frac-pi24-operator/454597#454597
The solution of this one follows along similar lines.  Please try it yourself and let us know where you are having difficulties.

Comment: Also, you realize of course that the problem posted here is a special case of the one I already solved for you?  You really need to recognize these patterns, otherwise you are not learning anything.  But thanks for posting nice problems for us anyway.

Comment: @RonGordon at this point of time and with all what i learned from book every thing is ok but my difficult problem is how to know the suitable contour for specific integral , the easiest contour is half circle but I faced many difficult with some copmlicated integral so I need to choose another contour and your old answer very usefull to me give me alot of information but I still have the same problem to choose suitable contour

Comment: @Did I can understand every thing you say to me but I havent the ability to tell you what I need to tell you 
and Iam sorry if I did some thing wrong ^_^

Comment: As @RonGordan , suggests . You can use the more general integral $$f(a)=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\sin(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}\, dx$$
The results follows by considering $f'(0)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming $a\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{\sinh(ax)}\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{2a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac1{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x+i\pi/2}{i(e^x+e^{-x})}\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{e^x+e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{e^{2x}+1}\mathrm{d}e^x\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2a^2}\int_0^\infty\frac1{u^2+1}\mathrm{d}u\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4a^2}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
**Explanation:**
$(1)$: Substitution $x\mapsto x/a$, use even function symmetry to extend range
$(2)$: $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$
$(3)$: move contour up $i\pi/2$
$(4)$: remove the odd part by symmetry
$(5)$: multiply by $\frac{e^x}{e^x}$
$(6)$: $u=e^x$
$(7)$: $u=\tan(\theta)$ substitution

In $(3)$, the integral along the contour $$[-R,R]\cup[R,R+\frac{i\pi}2]\cup[R+\frac{i\pi}2,-R+\frac{i\pi}2]\cup[-R+\frac{i\pi}2,-R]$$ is $0$ since there are no singularities of the integrand inside the contour. Since the integrand vanishes on $[R,R+\frac{i\pi}2]$ and $[-R,-R+\frac{i\pi}2]$, we can simply exchange the integral along $(-\infty,\infty)$ for $(-\infty+\frac{i\pi}2,\infty+\frac{i\pi}2)$.

Answer (score 13):

$$a>0:$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\,dx}{\sinh ax}=\frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\,dx}{\sinh x}=\frac{2}{a^2}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{e^{x}}\right)\frac{dx}{1-e^{-2x}}=\frac{2}{a^2}\int_0^{\infty}x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-(2k+1)x}\,dx$$

Now, since

$$\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-kx}\,dx=\frac{1}{k^2}$$

We have:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\,dx}{\sinh ax}=\frac{2}{a^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{4a^2}$$

The latter sum follows from:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

The case $a<0$ is dealt with by adding a negative.

Answer (score 6):

Let $x\to ax$ so we add $\frac 1{a^2}$

By contour, take the path as
 $$-R \to R \to R + i\pi \to \epsilon + i \pi \to \gamma \to -\epsilon + i \pi \to -R+ i \pi \to -R $$
[image]
The integral is 
$$\int_{-R}^R \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx +\int_0^{\pi} \frac{R + i y}{\sinh(R + iy )}i dy + \int_R^{\epsilon} \frac{x+i\pi}{\sinh(x+i\pi)}dx + \int_{\gamma } + \int_{-\epsilon}^{-R} \frac{x+ i \pi }{\sinh(x+i\pi)}dx + \int_{\pi}^0 \frac{R + iy}{\sinh(R + iy)}i dy  = 0$$

As $R\to\infty$, the second and the last integral vanishes from [Jordan's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma). The integral containig $R$
$$\int_{-R}^R \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx + \int_R^{\epsilon} \frac{x+i\pi}{\sinh(x+i\pi)}dx + \int_{-\epsilon}^{-R} \frac{x+ i \pi }{\sinh(x+i\pi)}dx = 4 \int_\epsilon^R \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx$$
The $\gamma$ curve part
$$\int_\gamma = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_0^{-\pi } \frac{i\pi + \epsilon e^{i\theta}}{\sinh(i\pi + \epsilon e^{i\theta})} i \epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta  =  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_0^{-\pi } \frac{\pi \epsilon e^{i\theta}}{\sinh(\epsilon  e^{i\theta})}d\theta  - i \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_0^{-
\pi} \frac{(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^2}{\sinh(\epsilon e^{i\theta})} d\theta =  - \pi^2 $$
Puttnig it all up you get, $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\lim_{\epsilon\to0} 4 \int_\epsilon^R \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx - \pi^2 = 0$$

Comment: (+1) another instructive contour integral; nice diagram, too

Answer (score 1):

Perform integration by parts,

$\begin{align} J&=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh ax}dx\\&=\left[\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)\right)x\right]_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)\right)dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}\ln\left(\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)\right)dx\\
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)$,

$\begin{align}J&=-\frac{2}{a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{2}{a^2}\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x}{1-x^2}dx-\frac{2}{a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx
\end{align}$

In the first intégral perform the change of variable $y=2x$,

$\begin{align}J&=\frac{1}{2a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx-\frac{2}{a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\frac{3}{2a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=\frac{3}{2a^2}\zeta(2)\\
&=\frac{1}{4a^2}\pi^2
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

With real method
\begin{align}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh ax}~dx
=& \int_{0}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{ax}}a \int_0^1 \frac{1 }{(e^{2ax}-1)y+1}dy\right)dx\\
=&\ \frac\pi{4a^2}\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy = \frac{\pi^2}{4a^2}
\end{align}