# Contour integral hyperbolic sine.

Tags: complex-analysis

I haven't found out a good contour to evaluate the following integral.

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x\cos ax}{\sinh x}dx$. Well, a natural way should consider the complex integral 
$\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}\dfrac{ze^{iaz}}{\sinh z}dz$.

However, I don't know how to find a suitable contour $\Gamma$ to surround the zeros of $\sinh z$ which are $z=\pi ni $ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Best regards.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454491/show-that-int-0-infty-fracx-cos-ax-sinh-xdx-frac-pi24-operator/454597#454597

Answer (score 0):

You may prove first that:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(ax)e^{-nx}\,dx = \frac{a}{a^2+n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a+ni}+\frac{1}{a-ni}\right) \tag{1}$$
holds by integration by parts, then by differentiating with respect to $a$:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cos(ax)e^{-nx}\,dx = \frac{n^2-a^2}{(n^2+a^2)^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(a+in)^2}+\frac{1}{(a-in)^2}\right)\tag{2}$$
follows, and:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(a+i(2n+1))^2}+\frac{1}{(a-i(2n+1))^2}\right) = -\frac{\pi^2}{4}\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right) \tag{3}$$
is a consequence of the Weierstrass product for the $\cosh$ function, since $\text{sech}(z)^2 = \frac{d}{dz^2}\log\cosh(z)$. By $(2)$ and $(3)$ you may easily compute your integral: just expand $\frac{1}{\sinh}$ as a geometric series.